# Pandas - Loc w/categories

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I'm trying to call a value by a set of index values in Pandas. When I create the bins using this method, I'm able to call the index values without issue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(100*np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=100),columns=['randoms'])
df['the']='the'
df['another']=100*np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=100)
bins=[0,50,100]
labels=['0-50','51-100']
df['cat']=df.randoms.apply(lambda x: '0-50' if x<=50 else '51-100')
x=df.groupby(['the','cat']).quantile(np.arange(0,1.1,.1))
x.loc['the','0-50']
```

However, I realized as my binning got more complex, I should use the pd.cut method. But when I do so, I get the following error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(100*np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=100),columns=['randoms'])
df['the']='the'
df['another']=100*np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=100)
bins=[0,50,100]
labels=['0-50','51-100']
df['cat']=pd.cut(df.randoms,bins,labels=labels)
x=df.groupby(['the','cat']).quantile(np.arange(0,1.1,.1))
x.loc['the','0-50']

KeyError: 'the label [0-50] is not in the [columns]'
```

However, these work fine in the second method:

```
x.loc['the']
x.loc['the','0-50',0]
```

What's going on here?

Comment: actually your code works for me, maybe try upgrading to the latest version of pandsa?

Comment: Are you sure the code set works for you? I upgraded to .18 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like it works fine in python 3.